Upgrading one smart switch in a double gang but there are 3 neutral wires
I am changing only one switch to smart in a double gang.  The box has three neutral wires.  What do I do with the third after using two for the smart switch?

Pictures.  Smart switches are connected to one neutral wire or to the neutral bundle, by one wire.

a.k.a. a pigtail.

Do you really have 3 Neutral wires, or do you actually have 3 White wires and you're assuming they're all Neutrals?

You don't "use" one or two of the neutral wires. Even if it worked that way, I am not sure how you would "use" two neutral wires for one switch.
All neutral wires on the same circuit in a given box (which most of the time, but not always, is all neutral wires in the box) are connected together. Dumb switches don't use neutral. Receptacles use neutral. Ongoing circuits (to switched lights or other switch boxes or receptacles) use neutral. Smart switches use neutral.
A typical setup is:

Incoming (from panel) white neutral
Outgoing (to switched light) white neutral
Outgoing (to another switched light) white neutral

are all connected together with a wire nut.
Then when you need to use neutral with a smart switch (replacing a dumb switch), you add a pigtail. Meaning:

Cut ~ 6" white pigtail wire (12 AWG if 20A circuit, 14 AWG or 12 AWG if 15A circuit) and strip the ends.
Remove the wire nut from the neutral bundle.
Add the pigtail to the bundle.
If the existing wire nut is large enough and in good condition, use it to connect the neutral bundle and the pigtail. If you are not sure, use a new appropriate size wire nut.
Connect the pigtail to the smart switch neutral.

You may see other white wires not connected to the bundle. Remember: neutral is always white, but white is not always neutral!

In "older" wiring WHITE wires were often used for line hot or switched hot between a wall switch and a light fixture. This came about because neutrals were not required in switch boxes so electricians used 14/2 cables and marked the white wire with a black mark to indicate change in use . In "newer" wiring every switch box has to have a (white) neutral in it. Does this mean that in wiring done since this change all whites are neutrals?

@JimStewart It should mean that. But aside from mistakes (which happen) or people who don't know the current rules (which happens, particularly with non-professionals), if a building predates the local jurisdiction adopting the relevant NEC change then it could have white-as-hot in any original circuits (or circuits added prior to the NEC change was adopted).
